# Preg-replace not removing '§'?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, special-characters

This code:

```
$text = preg_replace("/[^\s\-\_\@a-zA-Z0-9äáàëéèíìöóòúùñçÀÁÈÉÊÌÍÒÓÙÚ.,;]/", "", $text);
```

successfully removes special chars like *°+? ecc. I want to save whitespaces, "-", "_", "@", letters, number, accents, ".,;", "ñ" and "ç", nothing else.
It works fine, but it can't remove this: §

It's just an example so I could make a special rule, but I'm afraid that it can't remove other chars too.
Why is that? How can I remove absolutely everything that is not what I listed above?

Comment: Try `"/[^\\s_@a-zA-Z0-9äáàëéèíìöóòúùñçÀÁÈÉÊÌÍÒÓÙÚ.,;-]/u"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the `u` (*Unicode*) modifier. By placing this modifier after your regular expression pattern, it specifies additional functionality of PCRE and Pattern strings are treated as **UTF-8**.

```
$text = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9äáàëéèíìöóòúùñçÀÁÈÉÊÌÍÒÓÙÚ\s@.,;_-]/u', '', $text);
```

You can modify your character class as follows:

```
$text = preg_replace('/[^\pL\pN\s.,;@_-]+/u', '', $text);
```

The *Unicode* property [`\pL`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) includes regular `a-z` characters along with accented ones. `\pN` will match any kind of numeric character in any script; you can change it back to `0-9` if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

`§` (aka: SECTION SIGN) is encoded in utf8 with: `c2 a7`
`ç` (aka: LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CEDILLA) is encoded in utf8 with: `c3 a7`

The regex engine considers by default that each byte is a character. If I write something like this:

```
echo dechex(ord(preg_replace('~[^ç]~', '', '§')));
```

I will obtain `a7` because the negated character class contains all that are not the "characters" `c3` and `a7`.

You can tell the regex engine that the pattern string is utf8 encoded with the `u` modifier. With this modifier `ç` is no more seen as two separated bytes but as a group of bytes that stands for one character.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's clear now. I've also found 'mb_strlen' to correct the same problem when computing the length of a string with special chars.

Comment: @user2502368: `mb_strlen` can indeed be useful, but take care that the second parameter is the good encoding.